# How can I use stub to mock httpclient in C#

Tags: c#

How can I use stub to mock HTTP client while unit testing in c# code?

I don't want to use Moq because I have a method to create http client instance which is static but not virtual.

**Code:**

```
public static class HttpClientFactory
{
    public static IHttpClient httpClient;

    public static IHttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        if(httpClient == null)
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: static classes/methods do not lend themselves well to unit testing. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Problem with static classes and methods is that you can't easily replace them with mock implementations. The first refactor I would do is to make the factory a normal class and implement an interface to be injected whenever it's needed, then mock that interface to get fake http clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just make your `IHttpClient` non-static and get rid of factory ?

```
public interface IHttpClient {}
public class HttpClient : IHttpClient {}
```

And just mock `IHttpClient` and implement methods, then inject it (in constructor or property)

```
public class SomeStuff 
{
    public IHttpClient Client { get; }
    public SomeStuff(IHttpClient client) 
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}
```